# Адресация в ассемблере при помощи скобок

Tags: ассемблер

Не могу до конца разобратся в работе оператора [] в ассемблере. В пример привожу дизассемблированный листинг функции на си:

```
void xchg(int *a, int *b){
    int tmp;
    tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}



Breakpoint 2, 0x08048448 in xchg ()
(gdb) x/20i $eip
=> 0x8048448 <xchg+6>:  mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
   0x804844b <xchg+9>:  mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
   0x804844d <xchg+11>: mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],eax
   0x8048450 <xchg+14>: mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
   0x8048453 <xchg+17>: mov    edx,DWORD PTR [eax]
   0x8048455 <xchg+19>: mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
   0x8048458 <xchg+22>: mov    DWORD PTR [eax],edx
   0x804845a <xchg+24>: mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
   0x804845d <xchg+27>: mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
   0x8048460 <xchg+30>: mov    DWORD PTR [eax],edx
   0x8048462 <xchg+32>: nop
   0x8048463 <xchg+33>: leave  
   0x8048464 <xchg+34>: ret    
   0x8048465:   xchg   ax,ax
   0x8048467:   xchg   ax,ax
   0x8048469:   xchg   ax,ax
   0x804846b:   xchg   ax,ax
   0x804846d:   xchg   ax,ax
   0x804846f:   nop
   0x8048470 <__libc_csu_init>: push   ebp
(gdb)
```

Мне непонятны такие строчки:

```
0x8048448 <xchg+6>: mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
0x804844b <xchg+9>: mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
```

Сначала мы используем смещение в кадре стека (адрес локальной переменной) для получения числа и сохраняем его в еах. А что потом? Оператором [] снова получаем адрес числа в этом регистре и сохраняем его? Пишут, что иногда выражение [ ... ] это просто адрес, а не значение по этому адресу, и тогда в регистре сохраняется сам адрес, то есть скобки используются просто для вычисления арифметического выражения. Расскажите всё об этом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[]` - Это обращение по адресу, рассчитываемому в выражении в скобках. В переводе на язык С квадратные скобки в обычных инструкциях означают именно `*`. `mov eax,[X] => eax=*X`.

Но не надо путать инструкцию `mov` с `lea`. Вторая означает загрузку адреса, именно в ней значение в скобках кажется просто значением. `lea` чем то похожа на C оператор `&`. `lea eax,A => eax=&A` (с натяжкой). Соответственно `lea eax,[ebp+8] => eax=&(*(ebp+8)) => eax=ebp+8`

```
0x8048448 <xchg+6>:  mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]   eax=a
0x804844b <xchg+9>:  mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]       eax=*a
0x804844d <xchg+11>: mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],eax   tmp=eax (tmp=*a)
0x8048450 <xchg+14>: mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]   eax=b
0x8048453 <xchg+17>: mov    edx,DWORD PTR [eax]       edx=*b
0x8048455 <xchg+19>: mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]   eax=a
0x8048458 <xchg+22>: mov    DWORD PTR [eax],edx       *a=edx  (*a=*b)
0x804845a <xchg+24>: mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]   eax=b
0x804845d <xchg+27>: mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]   edx=tmp
0x8048460 <xchg+30>: mov    DWORD PTR [eax],edx       *b=edx  (*b=tmp)
```

ebp в данном случае указывает на текущий кадр стека (как принято в языках высокого уровня). Так как стек растет от старших адресов к младшим, то что кладется в стек первым - находится по бОльшему адресу. При вызове функции в стек кладутся ее параметры. Поэтому положительное смещение от ebp - это параметры функции, а отрицательные - в еще неиспользуемой области стека - локальные переменные.

Answer (score 0):

```
mov eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
;это переслать содержимое размером dword с адреса ebp+0x8 в eax 

mov eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
;это переслать содержимое по адресу в eax в регистр eax , размерность dword
```

Comment: Ну и что? Ведь когда пересылается содержимое по адресу в eax, там находится не адрес, а число, взятое из кадра стека.

Comment: @typemoon А почему бы числу из стека не быть адресом. Раз так обращаются с ним, значит это число точно адрес