# Как работает стек в случае локальных переменных?

Tags: c++, ассемблер, стек, машинный-код

Правильно ли я понимаю что когда у нас есть условно код

```
a = 5;
b = 3;
c = a + b;
```

при компиляции у нас произойдет следующее
компилятор выделит под переменную a 4 байта и положит их по адресу смещения 0 от начала фрейма стека принадлежащему данной процедуре
далее переменную b положит в следующие 4 байта с смещением уже 4 байта и т.д.
т.е. компилятор переводит это в следующие инструкции стирая переменные вобще

```
положи в первые 4 байта цифру 4
положи в 4 байта начиная с пятого цифру 3
возьми из первые 4 байт и сложи с 4 байтами начиная с 5 до 8
```

т.е. переменные вобще стерты и заменены адресами в стеке начиная с начала стека конкретной процедуры, верно?

Тогда не совсем понятно как это работает с интерпретируемым языками там ведь код выполняется построчно и мы не можем заранее заменить все переменные адресами.
Или там они размещаются не в стеке, а в куче?
Поясните пожалуйста как работает стек с локальными переменнами на примере или подскажите где подробней почитать.

Comment: Не цифру, а число...  

В общем-то примерно именно так — если забыть об оптимизации, размещении значений в регистрах и массе т.п. мелочей.  

А проблемы при интерпретации никакой: просто содержим таблицу соответствия переменных адресам в памяти, и при обращении загружаем/сохраняем значение оттуда, откуда надо.

Comment: т.е. значения лежат так же в стеке, но при этом еще есть таблица соответствий что переменная "a" лежит в нулевом смещении?

Comment: Интерпретатор делает так, как ему захочется. Если он пытается интерпретировать как есть, то да, он может разместить их в стеке. Но многие интерпретируемые языки требуют гораздо большего и за каждой переменной в программе стоит некий объект, где помимо самого значения храниться различная дополнительная информация, например счетчик ссылок для сбора мусора. И такие интерпретаторы создают все в куче или любом другом куске памяти на свое усмотрение

Comment: А может быть что для интерпретируемой программы интерпретатор создаст отдельный от своего стек или даже несколько стеков (для поддержания async/await, например). И разместит эти виртуальные стеки опять же где нибудь в куче. Это имеет смысл рассматривать сугубо в рамках конкретного языка и иногда в рамках конкретного интерпретатора, конкретного языка.

Comment: Понял! Но для компилируемых это будет работать примерно так как я описал в общем случае ? Т.е. фактически переменные заменяться адресами смещения ?

Comment: Да. Вот для примера вопрос-ответ с примером программы на C и ее виде на ассемлере. В тексте все обращения по ebp+X это как раз работа со стеком. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495492/%d0%90%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba/495498#495498

Comment: Понял. А вообще устройство стека и кучи и тп это больше относится к устройству компиляторов или конкретных языков не касаемо архитектуры компьютера или операционной системы? Я это к тому что где искать информацию поглубже книги по ассемблеру/с++ или ОС ?

Comment: Когда-то (еще в первом издании) мне очень понравилась одна серьезная книга эту тему [Языки программирования, разработка и реализация](https://ur.pb1lib.org/book/2879095/e7b1c6) (если получше поискать, то наверняка где-то есть pdf)

Comment: Здравствуйте, есть возможно глупый вопрос. Если мы сначала берем из стека первые 4 байта со дна, то какой же это стек? Нужно брать начиная с вершины, то есть сначала значение переменной `b` из примера.

Comment: А если будет так:
`a = 5;
b = 3;
c = 4;
a = 0;`
То есть чтобы достать `a` и присвоить ей новое значение, нужно пушить `c` и `b`? А куда их девать, в регистры? А если этих переменных 100 штук и последняя в стеке `a`, регистров ведь не напасешься

Comment: Или такой случай: `a1 = 5; a2 = 3; a3 = 4; . . . a100 = 6; a101 = a1 + 1; ` Как это вообще работает?

Comment: @Hatsan125 вам ничего не мешает обратиться к самому началу стеку и прочитать от туда значение, так и будет сделано, но вытаскивать вы из него ничего не будете. Если вы положили в стек 3 значения это абсолютно не означает что читать вы их должны строго в том порядке в каком они лежать. Другое дело извлекать и удалять. Но это уже другой пример, например у нас есть 2 переменные в стеке далее вы заходите в функцию там создаете 3 локальные переменные они кладутся в стек и используются внутри этой функции, а потом все вместе из стека удаляются и в стеке остаются снова 2 переменные.